# Error on displaying NSArray objectAtIndex into UILabel

Tags: objective-c, object, nsarray, uilabel

Despite many tries I have already done.. I am not getting to display correctly items from an NSArray into a UILabel..

When I NSLog the array the console returns me this:

```
2013-01-19 14:34:32.799 bloom[2766:c07] (
"0.877"
)
```

Which is the value I fetched from a website and parsed and etc..

The problem is that when I display it in a UILabel it shows me exactly the same thing and I need just the value without quotes to be displayed. Here's is how it is displaying:

[image: Displaying problem]

Edit:

Here is my code:

```
- (void)configureView
{
// Update the user interface for the detail item.

if (self.detailItem) {

    for (NSDictionary *valuesDatum in _detailItem) {
        NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)_detailItem;
        self.title = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"SYMBOL"];
        NSString *strUrl = @"http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/";
        NSString *ativo = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"SYMBOL"];
        NSString *consulta = [strUrl stringByAppendingString:ativo];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:consulta];

        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


        NSString *xPathQuery = @"//span[@class=' price'] | //span[@class=' trending_up  up'] | //span[@class=' trending_up up']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";

        TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithData:webData isXML:NO];

        NSArray *array = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQuery];

        valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (TFHppleElement *element in array) {
            [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
        }

        novosValores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSString *valuesDatum in valores) {
            NSString *removeNewLine = [[valuesDatum componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
            NSString *removeSpace = [removeNewLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"         " withString:@""];
            NSString *removeSpaceOne = [removeSpace  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@""];
            NSString *trocaVirgulaPonto = [removeSpaceOne stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];
            [novosValores addObject:trocaVirgulaPonto];
        }

        valoresFinais = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSString *valuesDatum in novosValores) {
            NSArray *val = [valuesDatum componentsSeparatedByString:@" - "];
            [valoresFinais addObject:val];
        }

        infos = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSArray *dados in valoresFinais) {
            NSArray *arrayDados = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:dados];

            for (NSString *teste in arrayDados) {
                NSArray *arrayTeste = [teste componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
                [infos addObject:arrayTeste];
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",[infos objectAtIndex:0]);

        NSString *fff = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [infos objectAtIndex:0]];
        [_detailDescriptionLabel setText:fff];
    }

    }
}
```

NEW EDIT:

I have this array:

```
2013-01-19 15:43:05.055 bloom[3564:c07] (
"7.730",
"0.020",
"0.26%",
"7.750",
"7.650-7.800",
"2.333.100",
"7.710",
"3.730-8.810",
"+4.04%"
```

)

All I need is a new array with the data from lines 5 and 8 separated by the "-".

So anyone has a light??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Pictures are not interesting - show us some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this question with the help of Anoop. I changed a bit his code and finally my code is like this:

```
for (NSDictionary *valuesDatum in _detailItem) {
        NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)_detailItem;
        self.title = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"SYMBOL"];
        NSString *strUrl = @"http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/";
        NSString *ativo = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"SYMBOL"];
        NSString *consulta = [strUrl stringByAppendingString:ativo];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:consulta];

        NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        NSString *xPathQuery = @"//span[@class=' price'] | //span[@class=' trending_up up'] | //span[@class=' trending_up up']/span | //table[@class='snapshot_table']/tr/td";

        TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithData:webData isXML:NO];

        NSArray *array = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xPathQuery];

        valores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (TFHppleElement *element in array) {
            [valores addObject:[[element firstChild] content]];
        }

        novosValores = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (NSString *valuesDatum in valores) {
            NSString *removeNewLine = [[valuesDatum componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
            NSString *removeSpace = [removeNewLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"         " withString:@""];
            NSString *removeSpaceOne = [removeSpace stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"    " withString:@""];
            NSString *removeSpaceTwo = [removeSpaceOne stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
            NSString *removeDash = [removeSpaceTwo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" - " withString:@" "];
            NSString *trocaVirgulaPonto = [removeDash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."];

            [novosValores addObject:trocaVirgulaPonto];
        }

        NSString *fullString=[novosValores componentsJoinedByString:@"_"];
        NSString *changeDash = [fullString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
        finalArray=[changeDash componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];
        //NSLog(@"%@", finalArray);

    }
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[finalArray objectAtIndex:10]];
    [_detailDescriptionLabel setText:str];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (
   "0.877"
)
```

The above is an array, and you are putting that array onto label.

You have to use `someLabel.text=[thatArray objectAtIndex:0];`

EDIT:

As per your requirement try this one: (not compiler checked)

```
NSString *fullString=[array componentsJoinedByString:@"+"];
NSArray *brokenString=[fullString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
NSString *mainString=brokenString[1];
NSArray *finalArray=[mainString componentsSepartedByString:@"+"];
```

Comment: try logging `fff`... and tell us, what it prints

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", fff); outputs:  2013-01-19 14:34:32.799 bloom[2766:c07] (
"0.877"
)

Comment: either your string contain parenthesis or again try by nslog(@"%@",[fff class]; if it is array use [fff objectAtIndex:0]; if it is string remove (, " and )....

Comment: If I use: _detailDescriptionLabel.text = [infos objectAtIndex:0]; it returns me an error:   2013-01-19 15:01:13.381 bloom[2961:c07] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8081d00
2013-01-19 15:01:13.381 bloom[2961:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8081d00'

Comment: I'll try to remove then and will report back.

Comment: Tried to remove and got back errors again:  2013-01-19 15:08:16.103 bloom[3017:c07] -[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1042edd0
2013-01-19 15:08:16.104 bloom[3017:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1042edd0'

Comment: see ur error, it says it is NSArray... and you are trying to use it as string.

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida, the objectAtIndex:0 is still an array -- you need to go one level down. Using the new syntax: [_detailDescriptionLabel setText:infos[0][0]];

Comment: I have edited my post to the actual status of the code and what I need from it.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I changed your code suggestion a bit and finally got it working!!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you make like this:

```
label.text = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

instead of:

```
label.text = array;
```